# how to get exect height and width of any images to used in imageView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, recyclerview-layout

I need a solution that how to find any images height and width that can fit totally in ImageView Height and width ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the image to stretch to your imageView?

Comment: My question was I have completed all the coding part in Android,Now I need images . so I was asking about how to find the images height and width of .png format image to set in my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can get image width and height by its drawable;

```
int width = imgView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = imgView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
```

And if you want your image to fit ImageView then you can use

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

But you have a low-resolution image then it will distort.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to fit inside the image view without image distortion

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```